# How to assign click events in TabItems?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I need to update a list as the user chooses which list to see. I created two items to the TabLayout and I'm trying to get the clik winds but I always get an error.

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/select_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabContentStart="32dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/posto1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Posto Shell" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@id/posto2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Posto Guanabara" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

The error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: posto2.setOnClickListener {
            if (lista != null){
                recycler_view_abastecimentos.adapter = ListaAbastecimentoAdapter(this, lista!!)
            }
        }

Comment: `TabItem`s don't end up as actual `View`s in the hierarchy, and those IDs aren't assigned to anything there. To listen for tab clicks, you want to set an `OnTabSelectedListener` on the `TabLayout`. Have a look here: https://material.io/components/tabs/android#using-tabs.